# Firebase Android getKey() returns child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the child below "ticket" with the key in between but not able to do it. Method getKey() is return "ticket" instead of the key.

```
private void getSpecificTicketFromFirebase() {
Timber.d("Inside Pull Data %s ",firebaseManager.getFireBaseUser().getUid()) ;
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(firebaseManager.getFireBaseUser().getUid()).child("ticket");
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  int i=0;
  @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      passengerData = data.getValue(PassengerViewModel.class);
      passengerViewModel.add(passengerData);
      Timber.d("Passenger Name %s index %s key %s",passengerViewModel.get(i).getFromStationName(),i,data.child("passengerName"));
      i++;
    }
  }

  @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Timber.e(databaseError.getDetails());
    Timber.e(databaseError.getMessage());
    Timber.e(databaseError.toException());
  }
});
```

}

[image: and the database structure]

Comment: Please add your code and database structure as text instead of an image. This makes it searchable and it can be used in a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get those objects of `PassengerViewModel` class, there is no need to use the `child()` method. Just remove this call: `.child(ref.getKey())` and your code will work perfectly fine.

If you want to pass that pushed key to the `child()` method, you need to store it first into a variable. To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
String key = ref.push().getKey();
```

Once you have this key, you can use it in any reference.

Comment: Now I'm doing `data.getValue(PassengerViewModel.class)` and then when I try to get `passengerViewModel.get(i).getPassengerName` the Value is NULL.

Comment: There is no need to use: `.get(i)`. Remove this method call. Does it work?

Comment: I'm doing`passengerData = data.child(firebaseManager.getFireBaseUser().getUid()).child("ticket").getValue(PassengerViewModel.class);` and then `passengerData.getPassengerName` but still it is NULL

Comment: Do I need to store `push.getKey()` result for each and every entry ? Why I can't get the key without storing it ?

Comment: Edit : Posted the answer. Beer on me @Alex. Thank you.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes it helped me to identify my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Thank you @AlexMamo....

Here is the correct way to do it.....

```
private void getSpecificTicketFromFirebase() {
DatabaseReference ref =
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(firebaseManager.getFireBaseUser().getUid()).child("ticket");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      Timber.d("Key %s",data.getKey());
    }
  }

  @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Timber.e(databaseError.toException());
  }
});
```